# Double summation, index change clarification.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

As my teacher is not really helpful and he's just writing on the blackboard and not explaining what he's doing I have a question how did he obtain this : 
$$ ... = \sum_{k=2}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{k-j} = |_{m=k-j} \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\frac{1}{m} = ... $$

I've been trying to figure out where did he get those summation indexes from but I still have no idea. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He’s simply made the substitution $m=k-j$ that he wrote next to the equals sign. It’s easy to see that that turns $\frac1{k-j}$ into $\frac1m$. To see what it does to the indexing of the sums, look at the pairs $\langle k,j\rangle$ for which the first double summation actually has terms:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
k\backslash j&1&2&3&\dots&n-1\\ \hline
2&\frac1{2-1}\\
3&\frac1{3-1}&\frac1{3-2}\\
4&\frac1{4-1}&\frac1{4-2}&\frac1{4-3}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\\
n&\frac1{n-1}&\frac1{n-2}&\frac1{n-3}&\cdots&\frac11
\end{array}$$

When $m=k-j$ is $1$, we get the terms on the top diagonal; when it’s $2$, we get the terms on the second diagonal; and so on, down to the single term $\frac1{n-1}$ with denominator $n-1$ on the $(n-1)$-st diagonal. The double summation on the righthand side, then, is summing by diagonals. The first, or $m=1$, diagonal has $n-1$ terms; the second has $n-2$ terms; and in general the $m$-th has $n-m$ terms. These terms are all $\frac1m$, so we could jump directly to $$\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-m}m\;,$$ but your instructor took an intermediate step that doesn’t require drawing (or at least imagining) the array above.

If $m=k-j$, then $j=k-m$, and

$$\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac1{k-j}=\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{k-m=1}^{k-1}\frac1m\;.$$

Now $m=k-(k-m)$, so as $k-m$ runs from $1$ to $k-1$, $m$ runs from $k-1$ to $k-(k-1)=1$. And we can certainly add up those terms in the opposite order without affecting the total, so

$$\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{k-m=1}^{k-1}\frac1m=\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{m=1}^{k-1}\frac1m\;.$$

Now just reverse the order of summation: if you look at all terms in the double sum, you see that $m$ can be anything from $1$ through $n-1$, and for each $m$, $k$ can be anything from $m+1$ through $n$, so

$$\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{m=1}^{k-1}\frac1m=\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac1m\;.$$

(This step is just like reversing the order of integration back in calculus.) Finally, for each $m$ there are $n-m$ values of $k$, so

$$\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac1m=\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-m}m=n\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac1m-\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}1=nH_{n-1}-(n-1)\;,$$

where $H_{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$-st [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer this Sir! It's been really helpful and I got a lot from it! Thanks!

Comment: @darenn: You’re very welcome; glad to help!

Answer (score 16):

Let me introduce you to Iverson's convention: $[condition]$ is 1 if $condition$ is true, 0 (very much so, so that multiplied by $\infty$ it still gives 0) otherwise. I also like to write sums by giving conditions on their indices as "subindex", that puts all together and also makes it easy to write sums e.g. over the elements of a set, not just boring 1, 2, 3, ..., $n$ ones. If no conditions on the index, anything goes there. If useful, smash several sums into one sum over a collection of indices.

In those terms:
$$
\sum_{2 \le k \le n} \sum_{1 \le j \le k - 1} \frac{1}{k - j}
   = \sum_k [2 \le k \le n] \sum_j [1 \le j \le k - 1] \frac{1}{k - j} \\
   = \sum_{j, k} [2 \le k \le n] \cdot [1 \le j \le k - 1] \cdot \frac{1}{k - j}
$$
We can juggle the sums around, as the outer $[]$ doesn't depend on $j$. And as the sums have *no* conditions once we moved those into $[]$, their order doesn't matter.

Now $[2 \le k \le n] \cdot [1 \le j \le k - 1]$ is 1 if both conditions are true,
i.e., we can combine/rearrange/separate:
$$
[2 \le k \le n] \cdot [1 \le j \le k - 1]
   = [1 \le j < k \le n]
   = [1 \le j < n] \cdot [j < k \le n]
$$
After doing the same steps as above in reverse, 
this gives the rearranged sums:
$$
\sum_{1 \le j \le n - 1} \sum_{j + 1 \le k \le n} \frac{1}{k - j}
$$

Comment: Thanks, will take my time to study this notation! :)

Comment: @darenn: And although I didn’t do it that way, I agree with vonbrand that it’s an excellent way to go, once you get used to it. You can find a little more on it [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), and the first half of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9205211) by Donald Knuth has lots of examples.